# How do I use MAAS custom commissioning scripts?

Tags: maas

I am attempting to use a custom MAAS commissioning script to perform custom operations on my MAAS cluster. When do these scripts run? How should they be named? Do they need to be in a particular format, or can they be executable shell scripts or binaries?

Answer (score 1):

Please find steps to achieve this:

Step 1: prepare shell script as per your requirement
Note: Commissioning scripts built into MAAS will have names starting with "00-maas" or "99-maas" to ensure that they run first or last, respectively.

Step 2 : Open MAAS Dashboard ( http://localhost:5240/MAAS/settings/ ) and Go to “Setting” tab.

Step 3 : Upload your shell script under commissioning script section.

Step 4 : Start commissioning for target machine and reboot the target machine.

Besides, following Restful MaaS API also available to perform the same.

List commissioning scripts:
GET /api/2.0/commissioning-scripts/

Create a new commissioning script:
POST /api/2.0/commissioning-scripts/

Ref: https://docs.ubuntu.com/maas/2.1/en/api

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking to accomplish with custom MAAS commissioning scripts? In my experience so far I have not had to load custom scripts and have made use of these examples and files in these locations installing MAAS and juju

http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/configure.html - this link will take you to some better examples of I *think* what your looking for.

```
/usr/share/maas/preseeds/generic
/usr/share/maas/preseeds/preseed-master
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: I am needing to modify them so that the drives are configured the way i need them. The servers have 160GB drive for the '/' a 1TB drive for the '/var'...

Comment: I want to thank you all for marking me DOWN when something isn't clear. If you can take the time to do that, then also tell me WHY it was negative. Should it have been that obvious then simply show me why. I do my best to keep professional and I expect that from those around me.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/636837/are-there-examples-of-custom-installation-scripts/636867#636867 for a more complete answer on customizing installation (as opposed to commissioning).