# Are there examples of custom installation scripts?

Tags: maas

I can't seem to find any information on how to provide a custom script to be run after installation. Are there examples on this that the community can provide?

Answer (score 4):

> Depending on which installer you are using, MAAS provides different mechanisms to customize an installation. This answer assumes you are using the [curtin installer](http://astokes.org/using-fastpath-installer-maas/) (also known as fast-path installer) which became the default in [MAAS 1.7](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2014/11/20/maas-1-7-one-maas-multiple-operating-systems/).

MAAS uses [cloud-init](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit) as part of its installation process. There are multiple ways to customize cloud-init behaviour, the easiest being simply providing a **User-Data Script**, which cloud-init executes during first boot, after the operating system installation is complete.

In MAAS, this can be accomplished by providing the user_data argument to the `node start` [CLI command](https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/maascli.html). The format of that command is:

```
maas <user> node start <node uuid> user_data=<script> distro_series=<name>
```

where `<script>` is actually a base64-encoded string. For a concrete example, assuming you would like to run a script called `addkey.sh` which prints some output to the installation console, [imports an SSH key from Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ssh-import-id) for the user `ubuntu`, and logs the results to a logfile:

```
#!/bin/sh
(
echo ======== Hi World ======================
echo ============== $(date) =================
ssh-import-id user
) | tee /my.log
```

you could issue the following commands:

```
$ script=$(base64 addkey.sh)
$ maas myuser node start node-79b67e82-d25c-11e4-a333-00163eca91de \
  user_data=$script distro_series=trusty
```

which if successful should return (after a while) output in the following format:

```
Success.
Machine-readable output follows:
{
    "status": 6, 
    "macaddress_set": [
        {
...
```

Now this runs that script after deployment of *one specific node*. If you'd like to have commands set up so they run on *any node* which is installed through MAAS,  you can add the commands to be run as part of the `late_commands` stanza in the [`/etc/maas/preseeds/curtin_userdata`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~maas-committers/maas/trunk/view/head:/contrib/preseeds_v2/curtin_userdata) file. For a more complex example which uses this mechanism to set up two VLANs on a network interface, see http://astokes.org/customizing-fastpath-curtin-installations/.

Note that Curtin is currently mostly undocumented; there is however an [overview file](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~curtin-dev/curtin/trunk/view/head:/doc/topics/overview.rst) that describes some of the detail of its operation.

Keep in mind this mechanism is not to be confused with a `comissioning script`, run during the **commissioning phase**, and which in the MAAS node life-cycle comes before installation. Commissioning is generally used for administrative tasks that are meant to not directly affect installation; examples would be:

- firmware updating
- sanity testing of key hardware components
- burn-in

Comment: If you are not using the curtin installer, but instead d-i, there is a description of using preseeds to do custom partitioning setup here: http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/configure.html

Comment: MAAS lacks support for cloud-init vendor data which would make specifying a standard command to be run simpler; see https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~cloud-init-dev/cloud-init/trunk/view/head:/doc/vendordata.txt for details

Answer (score 2):

It should be noted that the commands here are for the 1.0 API. In 2.0 and upwards, the command is:

```
maas <profile> machine deploy <system_id> user_data=<base64-encoded-userdata>
```